# Does .NET Peer to Peer Technology allows communication behind a router?

Tags: p2p, net.p2p

Recently i had a case where i was trying to establish a p2p connection using Microsoft PNRP technology between two applications. One application was on Lan and another was on same Lan (diff computer but same Service provider) but was behind a WiFi router. Since, I registered the two peers in all clouds(Global & local links) on respective system but when i tried to resolve the another i could not find the respective peers. As far as i know those peers must be discoverable since i also registered them in global cloud (Internet). How can i achieve the aforesaid scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PNRP in this way depends on a couple of technologies, the most important of which is Teredo tunnelling. You've probably run into a restriction of Teredo tunnelling and how it works behind firewalls.

To summarise it, Teredo routes IPv6 traffic over UDP packets sent to a specific port with IPv4. Because of this only certain kinds of NAT are supported for direct connections. You'll probably find that each of your systems can resolve themselves and other services, but not each other within the firewall if they're on different networks.

The easiest way for you to resolve this will be to either make the computers connect to completely different networks, or have them on the same network (as PNRP also supports link-local discovery).

More information can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling).